# NativeScript extension methods

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Is it possible to extend existing class in native script? By extending I mean it in C# terminology, e.g. not inherit, but 'inject' method to existing class and call that method on instance of original class.

C# extension methods:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int WordCount(this String str)
    {
        return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, 
                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
    }
}   

string s = "Hello Extension Methods";  
int i = s.WordCount();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript allows you to change the prototype of any object; so you can do:

```
String.prototype.wordCount = function() {
  var results = this.split(/\s/);
  return results.length;
};

var x = "hi this is a test"
console.log("Number of words:", x.wordCount());
```

and it will output `Number of words: 5`.

You can also use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to add properties (rather than functions) like so:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "wordCount", {
  get: function() {
    var results = this.split(/\s/);
    return results.length;
  },
  enumerable: true,  
  configurable: true
});

    var x = "hi this is a test"
    console.log("Number of words:", x.wordCount); // <-- Notice it is a property now, not a function
```